# XSLT: adding key based on another key in XML

Tags: php, xml, xslt

It is possible with XSLT to check for  value and create another key under it?

```
<url>http://xy.com/380094.jpg</url>
```

Where 380094 is the `<product_code>`.

and remove childs, where the available key is No.

`<available>No</available>` -

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
 <produkt>
  <product_code>380094</product_code>
  <nazov_produktu>loremipsum</nazov_produktu>
  <strucny_popis_produktu></strucny_popis_produktu>
  <popis_produktu>loremipsum</popis_produktu>
  <znacka>LOREMIPSUM</znacka>
  <available>Yes</available>
  <mj>ks </mj>
  <cena>999</cena>
 </produkt>
 <produkt>
  <product_code>000161</product_code>
  <nazov_produktu>loremipsum2</nazov_produktu>
  <strucny_popis_produktu></strucny_popis_produktu>
  <popis_produktu></popis_produktu>
  <znacka>LOREM</znacka>
  <available>No</available>
  <mj>sad</mj>
  <cena>19,90</cena>
 </produkt>
</xml>
```

Example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
 <produkt>
  <product_code>380094</product_code>
  <url>http://xy.com/380094.jpg</url>
  <nazov_produktu>loremipsum</nazov_produktu>
  <strucny_popis_produktu></strucny_popis_produktu>
  <popis_produktu>loremipsum</popis_produktu>
  <znacka>LOREMIPSUM</znacka>
  <available>Yes</available>
  <mj>ks </mj>
  <cena>999</cena>
 </produkt>
</xml>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post your XSLT (preferably minimized).

Comment: Here it is. For now, it just filter out availability (Thanks to @Patrick Bracken) http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTT

Comment: I meant your *existing* XSLT code. You mentioned a second run; I would want to see the first run. You mentioned adding a second key; I would want to see the first key. I am also not sure where exactly the code `<url>http://xy.com/380094.jpg</url>` is found.

Comment: Ther is no other XSLT at the moment. :) I mentioned second run in the sense, if we found any solution to the first run. The first run: get `<product_code>`, then create new key based on `<product_code>. <url>http://xy.com/'<product_code>'.jpg</url>`.

Comment: IMHO, it is not necessary to have two runs. This is why I am asking about the first run - to show you how to combine the two into one. However, I (still) don't understand your description of it.

Comment: Here's what I've done so far: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTT/3 It works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a select like

```
select=produkt[available != 'No']
```

So if you are in a loop for example

```
<xsl:for-each select=produkt[available != 'No']>
    //do stuff
</xsl:for-each>
```